# Five friends meeting at the same coffeehouse

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Five friends agree to meet at Joe's Coffeehouse in Capital City. However, there are $5$ different Joe's Coffeehouse locations in Capital City, and the friends neglected to agree on which one to meet at, so they each choose one at random. What is the probability that

> (a) they all end up at the same Joe's?

> (b) they all end up at different Joe's?

For each of those parts I solved it in two different ways and got different answers, I'm not sure which one is correct in both cases. Any explanation as to which is correct, which is wrong, and why would be very well appreciated.

(a) **APPROACH 1:** Let's fix a friend, there's a ${1\over5}$ chance of him going to each particular Joe's, and then for each of those $5$ options for the remaining $4$ friends, there's a ${1\over5}$ chance of going to that same Joe's, so the probability they all end up at the same Joe's is:$$\left({1\over5}\right)\left({1\over5}\right)^4 + \left({1\over5}\right)\left({1\over5}\right)^4 + \left({1\over5}\right)\left({1\over5}\right)^4 + \left({1\over5}\right)\left({1\over5}\right)^4 + \left({1\over5}\right)\left({1\over5}\right)^4 = \left({1\over5}\right)^4 = {1\over{625}}$$

**APPROACH 2:** The probability is going to be$${{\# \text{ of nonnegative integer solutions to }x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 5 \text{ such that }x_i = 5 \text{ for some }i \text{ between }1\text{ and }5 \text{ inclusive}}\over{\# \text{ of nonnegative integer solutions to }x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 5}} = {5\over{\binom{9}{5}}} = {5\over{126}}$$

(b) **APPROACH 1:** Let's fix a friend, there's a ${1\over5}$ chance of him going to each particular Joe's, and so for that particular Joe's, there's a ${4\over5}$ chance of the next guy going to a different Joe's, a ${3\over5}$ for the next guy etc. so the probability they all end up at different Joe's is:$$5 \left({1\over5}\right)\left({4\over5}\right)\left({3\over5}\right)\left({2\over5}\right) \left({1\over5}\right) = {{24}\over{625}}$$

**APPROACH 2:** The probability is going to be$${{\# \text{ of nonnegative integer solutions to }x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 5 \text{ such that }x_i = 1 \text{ for all }i \text{ between }1\text{ and }5 \text{ inclusive}}\over{\# \text{ of nonnegative integer solutions to }x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 5}} = {1\over{\binom{9}{5}}} = {1\over{126}}$$

Comment: Approach 1 is right in both cases. I don't know your reasoning for approach 2, maybe you could explain why you think it should be correct?

Comment: I honestly didn't understand approach 2 of both the parts, but approach 1 is definitely correct, along with your logic.

Comment: you are making a very common mistake in approach $2$. The outcomes are not equally probable in approach $2$. As a general rule, avoid using stars and bars when finding probability.

Comment: @MathLover Can you elaborate your comment into an answer here? I don't see what you mean.

Comment: @Vivek am I ignorant for not recognising their method or is it just not a good method?

Comment: @Vivek I mean method two

Comment: @EmperorConcerto Stars and Bars is a combinatorial technique that is tricky to apply to probability is what I think they meant

Comment: @IdioticShrike The approach he used in method 2 is not applicable here, I guess.

Comment: @EmperorConcerto Brian Moehring's example should help.

Comment: I've heard the name "stars and bars technique" for the first time, though I am aware of something called method of fictitious partition in combinatorics. Is that related to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with your methods, but I have worked out a solution to both, two different ways, with answers that agree with your answers in approach one.

Method one:

Take the first case:

One friend will definitely go to one shop. The next friend has a $1/5$ probability of visiting that shop, as do the rest of the friends. The probability here is $(1/5)^4=1/625$.

Second case:

One friend will definitely go to one shop. The next friend has a $4/5$ probability of not visiting their shop. The next has $3/5$,... and so on; the total probability is $4!/5^4=24/625$.

Method two:

There are $5\times5\times5\dots=5^5$ total outcomes. Label shops 1-5 as letters A-E. E.g., such an outcome might be “AABED” which says which friend went to which shop.

First case:

Now the event where they are all in one shop happens five times: “AAAAA,BBBBB,...” and so we have probability $5/(5^5)=1/5^4=1/625$, which is what I calculated before.

Second case:

To be all in different shops, we have a string “ABCDE” and all its $5!$ permutations. $5!/5^5=(5\cdot 4!)/5^5=4!/5^4=24/625$ as I said before.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

The $\binom{9}{5}$ outcomes you're considering in the second approaches aren't equally likely, so you cannot compute the probability as the number of favorable outcomes divided by the number of total outcomes.

As an analogous problem, if you flip a coin twice, you get three outcomes: 2 heads, 2 tails, or one of each; however, these categories of outcomes aren't equally likely.

Comment: @EmperorConcerto see MathLover’s comment

Comment: @EmperorConcerto I've added an analogous but simpler problem.  If you can see how it's the same issue, it might help.

Answer (score 2):

Your method $1$ for the cases is absolutely correct, along with explanation.
Regarding method $2$, we cannot apply stars and bar method in this case. Take the example, we have to put $n$ indistinguishable balls in $k$ distinguishable cans. Here you can apply the stars and bar method because balls are indistinguishable, it doesn't matter which ball is going to which can, it does not increase the number of cases. But in the given question, all $5$ people are distinguishable. It does matter which person is going to which restaurant and it will also increase the number of cases, as described in your approach $1$.
If you still have doubt, you can go through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics) .

Comment: Whether they are distinguishable or not affects how we can count them but it doesn't change the probabilities.  Even if the 5 friends were indistinguishable, the first step in computing the probability would be to give them name tags with distinct names, distinguishing them.